# Why will standard scrapy scrape an API but selenium version returns 401 error?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I'm using a selenium driven scrapy scraper to scrape a website to avoid detection as a bot. Within the site are a number of APIs that I can call to get data without downloading a whole page. However, I keep getting a 401 error from the following:

```
import logging

from scrapy import Request, Spider, signals
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler, CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxOptions

import scrape.constants as cs


class FlashscoreMiddleware:
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler: Crawler):
        middleware = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(middleware.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(middleware.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return middleware

    def spider_opened(self, *_) -> None:
        self.driver = Firefox()

    def spider_closed(self, *_) -> None:
        self.driver.quit()

    def process_request(self, request: Request, **_) -> None:
        self.driver.get(request.url)
        return HtmlResponse(
            request.url,
            body=self.driver.page_source,
            encoding="utf-8",
            request=request,
        )


class FlashscoreSpider(Spider):
    name = "flashscore"
    custom_settings = {
        "DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES": {"selenium_scraper.FlashscoreMiddleware": 400},
        "REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION": "2.7",
        "LOG_LEVEL": logging.ERROR,
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(
            url="https://global.flashscore.ninja/5/x/feed/df_st_1_WKM03Vff",
            headers={
                "X-Fsign": "SW9D1eZo",
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36",
            },
            callback=self.parse,
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        if response.text.startswith("SE÷Match"):
            print(f"Successfully returned {response.url}")
        else:
            print("Unsuccessful")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(FlashscoreSpider)
    process.start()
```

If I use a standard scrapy scraper though - all is fine:

```
import logging

from scrapy import Request, Spider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class FlashscoreSpider(Spider):
    name = "flashscore"
    custom_settings = {
        "REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION": "2.7",
        "LOG_LEVEL": logging.ERROR,
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(
            url="https://global.flashscore.ninja/5/x/feed/df_st_1_WKM03Vff",
            headers={"X-Fsign": "SW9D1eZo"},
            callback=self.parse,
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        if response.text.startswith("SE÷Match"):
            print(f"Successfully returned {response.url}")
        else:
            print("Unsuccessful")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(FlashscoreSpider)
    process.start()
```

Why is the selenium version not returning the correct result?

Comment: The reason for 401 errors depends on the site, there's no general answer to a question like this. You need to reverse-engineer the criteria they're checking for.

Comment: That's where I need some help! I've looked at the request that's generated and the only difference between the headers and the body are that the scrapy version announces itself as a scrapy scraper by way of the user-agent. I would have thought that would have had the opposite effect!!! What else should I check for?

Comment: Did you try to disable JS in Selenium driven browser, to see if it works?

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus - just tried `options = FirefoxOptions(); options.set_preference('javascript.enabled', False); self.driver = Firefox(options)` and getting same result. However, when I check the browser JS is still enabled so clearly the setting didn't take...